# ORA-01861 - Input seems ok and FX/FM modifiers not used

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-sql-developer, exception

Using SQL Developer 4, I am getting an ORA-01861 exception when I do the following (and BTW, I ticked 'Ignore NLS Definitions'):

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YY';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS';

select value from lpp_n3_qas.mes_piece_char pc
join lpp_n3_qas.mes_char_def cd on cd.mes_char_def_id = pc.mes_char_def_id
where
  cd.char_name = 'DispatchTimestamp' and
  value is not null and
  to_timestamp(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= '09-OCT-13' and
  to_timestamp(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') < '16-OCT-13';

----
01862. 00000 -  "the numeric value does not match the length of the format item"
*Cause:    When the FX and FM format codes are specified for an input date,
           then the number of digits must be exactly the number specified by the
           format code.  For example, 9 will not match the format specifier DD but
           09 will.
*Action:   Correct the input date or turn off the FX or FM format specifier
           in the format string.
```

But when I do this:

```
select to_timestamp(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as Dispatch_Timestamp from lpp_n3_qas.mes_piece_char pc
join lpp_n3_qas.mes_char_def cd on cd.mes_char_def_id = pc.mes_char_def_id
where
  cd.char_name = 'DispatchTimestamp' and
  value is not null;

DISPATCH_TIMESTAMP
------------------
09-OCT-13 11:20:06                         
09-OCT-13 11:20:06                         
11-OCT-13 16:33:13                         
11-OCT-13 16:44:25                         
15-OCT-13 11:23:54
```

I get no exceptions at all and I used the exact same to_timestamp() conversion.

In addition, if I take one record from the dataset and replace 'value' with it in the first query's where clause I also get no exceptions. The problem doesn't seem to be a bad input timestamp and I don't have any idea about what is going on. Can someone please shed some light?

Comment: what is the datatype for column 'Value' and can you show sample data? what happens when you replace '16-OCT-13' with to_timestamp('16-OCT-13','dd-mon-yy') and same for the other string?

Comment: Do you want to use 2 or 4 digits for Year? PS: you can also use "RR" and "RRRR" for year.

Comment: Raj: 
The datatype is varchar2. A small sample dataset:
`01/03/2014 05:55:11
01/03/2014 14:53:51
01/03/2014 14:53:56
01/03/2014 14:54:20
01/03/2014 14:54:27
01/03/2014 14:53:50
01/03/2014 14:53:55
01/03/2014 14:54:24`
And I get the same exception if I replace the strings with to_timestamp().

Comment: ibre5041: I need 4 digits for Year. Same exception using RRRR.

Comment: Use a to_timestamp variation of the first answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417258/finding-a-bad-datetime-stamp-in-oracle-10g to find the bad data, as that's certainly the cause